# how can I store a string without "" in common lisp?

Tags: string, parsing, common-lisp

Im trying to store in a:

```
 (seft a (read-from-string "."))
```

in order to get `a = .` not `a = "."` but it doesnt work.

Comment: What is the type you expect `.` to have? A symbol? Did you try `(make-symbol ".")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` and `read-from-string` are meant for reading (and parsing) lisp objects. If your string contains any kind of character, you have a couple of options, depending on what you want to do with the input. If the input is indeed supposed to be lisp, and you want to simply ignore strange elements, surround with

```
(ignore-errors (read-from-string "."))
```

If you do want to process the input then you need to save the string and then process it one character at a time with all the provided string functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a symbol `.`, then you have to quote it:

```
CL-USER 109 > (progn (princ '|.|)
                     (princ '\.)
                     (values))
..
```